# Matrix representing a transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $T: F \to \Bbb R^3$ be the application that matches each matrix
$A = (a_{i j})$ of $F$ the vector $(a_{12} + a_{13}, a_{13} + a_{23}, a_{23})$ of $\Bbb R^3$, i.e., 
$$
T(\pmatrix{
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}}) = \pmatrix{a_{12} + a_{13}\\ a_{13} + a_{23}\\ a_{23}}
$$

Determine the matrix representing $T$ with respect to the base of the previus point
and canonical basis of $\Bbb R^3$.

Could you help me, how do I it?

Comment: I'm going to start helping by editing your question to use MathJax, which is how we format things nicely here. But while I do, you can think about adding an explanation of what you've tried, what ideas you've had, etc. (You can add these by clicking "edit" below your question, but wait 3 minutes until I've prettied things up, please.)

Comment: By the way, "base of the point anterior" doesn't make a lot of sense in English. Any chance you can clarify that? Could it be "the basis already described"? If so, can you please include the description of that basis?

Comment: I tried to do it for a generic matrix, but it's not intended
Taking the values directly also did not give

Comment: I have no ideas on how to try to solve
help-me

Comment: Your new title makes no sense because your question is not about "changes of canonical coordinates"

Answer (score 2):

You don't explain what "the base of the previus (sic) point" is supposed to mean.  I assume that you are referring to the basis of $\Bbb R^{3 \times 3}$ given by
$$
\mathcal M = \left\{
\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0},
\pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}, \dots,
\pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1}
\right\}.
$$
Let $M$ denote the matrix representing $T$ with respect to $\mathcal M$ and the canonical basis $\mathcal B$ of $\Bbb R$, which is given by
$$
\mathcal B = \{(1,0,0)^T,(0,1,0)^T,(0,0,1)^T\}.
$$
Note that $M$ will be a matrix with $3$ rows and $9$ columns.  To find the $k$th column of $M$, compute the output of $T$ corresponding to the $k$th basis vector of $\mathcal M$. For instance: to find the third column of $M$, we see what $T$ does to the third basis element in $\mathcal M$.  In particular,
$$
T \pmatrix{0&0&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0} = \pmatrix{1\\1\\0}
= 1 \cdot (1,0,0)^T + 1\cdot (0,1,0)^T + 0\cdot (0,0,1)^T.
$$
These coefficients form the third column of $M$.  That is, we have
$$
M = \pmatrix{?&?&1&?&?&?&?&?&?\\
?&?&1&?&?&?&?&?&?\\
?&?&0&?&?&?&?&?&?\\}.
$$
In fact, because our basis of the second space is the standard basis, the third column is simply the output from the third element of $\mathcal M$.

The rest of the columns can be found in a similar fashion.